# подгрузка данных скроллингом

Tags: javascript, jquery, прокрутка, lazyloading, content

Накидал код, делающий подгрузку данных при событии скроллинга. Проблема в том, что загрузка идет по 1-му блоку. Скажите пожалуйста, как сделать загрузку по 10 блоков? Думаю, что дело в first(). Но не знаю, на что его заменить. Спасибо.

```js
$('.blog_content:lt(10)').css("display", "flex");
    $(window).scroll(function (event) {
        var top = $(window).scrollTop();
         if(top >= $("html").height()){
            $('.blog_content:hidden').first().css("display", "flex");
         } else {}
});
```

Comment: замените `first` на `slice(0, 10)`

Comment: не помогло...((

Comment: Потому что теперь возвращается массив объектов, а у него нет метода css нужно перебрать элементы и у каждого вызвать данный метод!

Comment: этот код не подгрузку делает, а отображение.

Comment: да, все верно, отображение) это я уже так, ошибочно написал.

Comment: почему-то первые 10 вы показать в первой строке кода смогли, а 10 из скрытых таким же образом отобразить нет